# How to make a get image by a NETObject

Tags: .netlink, clipboard

This more then a `.net` question but I'm in `Mathematica` using.Suppose I want to get a image from my clipboard,so I make a function like following.If  there is a image in your clipboard then you run this code.You will get a *image NETObject*:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard", StaticsVisible -> True];
img=GetImage[]

(*« NETObject[System.Drawing.Bitmap]»*)
```

How to make the `img` be a image?There is a related post:

- [Clipboard with
  transparency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28280/21532)

But his image from a `Mathemtica` expresssion.

Comment: LockBits or something like it might be needed; unfortunately my .NET is not up to snuff.

Comment: @J.M. It's little difficult as my Google.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18727243) is example code which does what you want in matlab. It is not completely straightforward to translate to Mathematica but a good starting point. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to solve? I could imagine that there might be other possibilities to achieve what you need than using .NET. See e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3094/169) for an alternative to get a picture from clipboard.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Wow,thanks for your links.Actually I have found [that post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3094/169)before this,I just want to convert a image object to image in `Mathematica`. :)

Comment: so you are saying that the .NET image object you are trying to convert does not necessarily come from the clipboard and the clipboard reference is just for an easy example? If so, you might want to make that more clear in your question to avoid answers explaining the `Clipboard` notebook solutions or even close votes as it could be seen as a duplicate to the one I linked to...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well I check my presentation,I found it is suitable for a .NET qeuestion in `Mathematica` I think?I just by clipboard to get a content. :)

Comment: Probably related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95938/using-a-pointer-in-netlink

Comment: @J.M. As your promption,I made it in a efficient way.Thanks a lot..

Comment: You're learning the usage of .netlink and don't want to use `Paste`?

Comment: @xzczd The `Paste` will not give any output,isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzkY2.gif

Comment: @xzczd It is a print,but a output. :)

Comment: Then you just need this function: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41722/1871

Comment: OK, since OP is just interested in the usage of .netlink, let me keep this in comment rather than posting an answer: if one only needs to _output_ the picture on the clipboard into _Mathematica_, I think using ``Paste[];
pic = ToExpression@First@NotebookRead@Experimental`NextCell[];
NotebookDelete@Experimental`NextCell[]; pic`` is simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done

```
Needs["NETLink`"]; InstallNET[];
LoadNETType /@ {"System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard", 
   "System.Drawing.Rectangle", "System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode",
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal"};
img = Clipboard`GetImage[];
width = img[Width];
height = img[Height];
lock = img[
   LockBits[Rectangle`FromLTRB[0, 0, width, height], 
    ImageLockMode`ReadWrite, img[PixelFormat][Format24bppRgb]]];
stride = Abs[lock[Stride]];
intPtr = lock[Scan0];
totalB = stride*height;
byte = NETNew["System.Byte[]", totalB];
Marshal`Copy[intPtr, byte, 0, totalB];
data = NETObjectToExpression[byte];
Marshal`Copy[byte, 0, intPtr, totalB];
img[UnlockBits[lock]];
img = Image[Map[Reverse/@Partition[#, 3] &,Partition[data, width*3,stride]],"Byte"]
```

Comment: Looks good. Though the `Compile` is a bit strange as it uses global variables width and stride that should be passed as parameter or derived locally. Compile, as used here, is also not faster. BTW `Image[Map[Reverse,  ArrayReshape[Drop[data, {stride, -1, stride}], Length[data]/stride, width, 3}], {2}], "Byte"]` would be an alternative to your last line, though it's just as fast as what you have.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much of .net and it probably shows, but at least I got something to work albeit very,very slowly.

Your code (which I also turned into a bitmap on the clipboard using Mathematica's "Copy as Bitmap" menu item):

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard", StaticsVisible -> True];
img = GetImage[]
```

Using a few of .Net's Image methods to get pixel information:

```
res = Table[
   {
    img@GetPixel[r, c]@R,
    img@GetPixel[r, c]@G,
    img@GetPixel[r, c]@B,
    img@GetPixel[r, c]@A
    }, {c, 0, img@Height - 1}, {r, 0, img@Width - 1}];

Image[res, "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

And after waiting perhaps a few minutes (I said it was slow) with the above mentioned image already loaded in the clipboard you get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow,it's seem you make it.Thanks very very much. :)

Comment: Feel free for the extra bounties please. :)